# Dingle vs. Bondi: Twin Paradox Debate on BBC radio?

Tags: special-relativity, soft-question, specific-reference, history, twin-paradox

Herbert Dingle and H. Bondi debated the twin paradox on BBC radio before 1971. Does anyone have a link to the audio of this debate? thanks